# When converting from hg to git, can fast-export filter out folders that we don't want to move?

Tags: git, mercurial

Our organization will be moving from Mercurial to Git soon. As part of the process I wanted to take the opportunity to exclude certain folders from the new repo.

Can Fast-Export filter by folder?

If Fast-Export can't do it, I may look at doing an hg to hg conversion first. I think that tool has a way of excluding folders.

Alternately, is there a way to edit the history of the new git repo to completely remove certain folders before uploading it back to Bitbucket/GitHub?

Comment: Using hg convert to form a new, modified repository, and then converting that to git sounds right to me. I'm not familiar with how to modify history on the git side, and that might work also.

Answer (score 1):

> Can Fast-Export filter by folder?

No. You have to use convert extension

> is there a way to edit the history

Yes. History alteration is a core feature of Git